# Special excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have excel data. Names in rows and data about names in columns:

```
Name Data1 Data2 Data3 ...
AA     1     7     5   ...
BB     8     5     3   ...
CC     5     9     7   ...
...   ...   ...   ...  ...
```

Now imagine conditional formatting in each column - highlight top 10% values in each column. That is easy conditional formatting what can I do.

But my question is: How to highlight rows which has let's say 3 and more highlighted cells by conditional formatting in columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of using VBA, you'd need to "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."  In that formula, add each condition found on the row, and format the cell if the sum >= 3.

In the following example, data is conditionally formatted if it's within the top 20% value per column:

[image]

We need a formula that determines if 3 or more data points are within the top 20% per column.

If a number is in the top 20% of a dataset, it's in the 80th percentile.  (100% - 20% = 80%).  Excel has a `PERCENTILE` function, which is just what we need.

`=PERCENTILE(A$1:A$15,0.8)` returns the number 8.  So any value 8 and above should be highlighted, which we see in the example.

We would get TRUE or FALSE if we compared each value in the A column with the percentile.  I've done the same for all columns below, giving us a grid of TRUEs and FALSEs.

[image]

Now we need to determine if there are 3 or more TRUEs.  This is easy to do, because TRUE is represented as a 1 in Excel, and FALSE is represented as a 0.  So we can add the TRUEs and FALSEs per row:

[image]

Combine all this work into a conditional format formula, and this is what you get:

```
=($A1>=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$15,0.8))+
 ($B1>=PERCENTILE($B$1:$B$15,0.8))+
 ($C1>=PERCENTILE($C$1:$C$15,0.8))+
 ($D1>=PERCENTILE($D$1:$D$15,0.8))+
 ($E1>=PERCENTILE($E$1:$E$15,0.8)) >= 3
```

I used the above formula for my example data, so rows with 3 or more highlighted cells get bold numbers and red borders:

[image]

Comment: Did you realy try this? Because your formula gives me error, even formula =($A1>=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$15,0.8)) >= 3 gives error.

Comment: Yes, these are actual screenshots.  What error do you get?

Comment: As "pnuts" pointed, I didnt use the delimiter appropriate for my locale :)

Comment: Whew, sorry I didn't think of that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Select columns B:F (here five data columns are assumed, the formula would need extra terms for more than that) and as a Conditional Formatting formula rule apply:

```
=IF($B1>=LARGE($B:$B,COUNT($B:$B)/10),1)+IF($C1>=LARGE($C:$C,COUNT($C:$C)/10),1)+IF($D1>=LARGE($D:$D,COUNT($D:$D)/10),1)+IF($E1>=LARGE($E:$E,COUNT($E:$E)/10),1)+IF($F1>=LARGE($F:$F,COUNT($F:$F)/10),1)>2
```

with formatting of your choice (presumably that does not conflict with that for the 10% formatting). Column labels will also be formatted unless range is abbreviated.

Comment: That was the problem :)